# Toolbar menu item text gets chopped off

Tags: android, menuitem, android-toolbar

I have a tool bar with few menu items in it. Some of the menu items are displayed clear but few of then are getting chopped off. In have tried support:anyDensity in menifest but it is also not working. I have not applied any padding programmatically. Here are the screen shots of how my toolbar currently[image: toolbar currently] looks like in landscape mode. The left part of the tool bar is looking fine but the text and image in right part seems to be having some padding in it.

[image: this]

this is the screenshot for potrait mode.

My layout file for tool bar is,

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And the menu item file is,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/waiter_name"
        android:title="Waiter Name"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh_table"
        android:title="Refresh Table"
        android:visible="false"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh_product"
        android:title="Refresh Menu"
        android:visible="false"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_password"
        android:onClick="changePassword"
        android:title="Change Password"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_passcode"
        android:title="Change Passcode"
        android:onClick="changePasscode"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_select_printer"
        android:title="Select Printer"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_update"
        android:title="Check for updates"
        android:visible="false"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/about_us"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:onClick="aboutUs"
        android:title="About Us"/>
</menu>
```

I have been through some of the posts in stackoverflow but none of these helped me.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Add showAsAction to all the item and specify when the icon is to be showed such as "ifRoom" or "always"

Answer (score 0):

if room is an option it might not show sometime due to space availability issue. use always so that you can force item to be shown over toolbar.

```
   <item
                android:id="@+id/action_search"
                android:title="Search"
                android:icon="@drawable/search"
                app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
                app:showAsAction="always"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/waiter_name"
                android:title="Waiter Name"
                app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but i have already tried this and it is not helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
?attr/actionBarSize is 46 dp.
```

But the new toolbar's default height is 56dp. So update your toolbar height to 56dp.

Metrics

Default toolbar heights:

- Mobile Landscape: 48dp
- Mobile Portrait: 56dp
- Tablet/Desktop: 64dp

[More here.](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

Comment: I have already tried using hard coded dimen size of 70dp. And even more.. It does not seem like it is having problem with the size of toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Check your icon size and the icon padding.

Toolbar icon size is 48dp

Viewport 24dp

Clickable area 48dp

Comment: I have used 24dp icon.